# PostgreSQL JDBC driver uses JVM time zone when converting LocalDateTime at DST boundary

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jdbctemplate, jdbc-postgres

Why is a LocalDateTime value on the DST transition of the JVM's timezone shifted by one hour when it is passed to PostgreSQL by the current jdbc driver (42.5.4)?  I understood from the docs that LocalDateTime should be passed through as if it were wall clock time.

I did this:

1. Create a demo project from [spring initializr](https://start.spring.io/) with jdbc and postgres
2. Execute the following against a local database (`template` is an instance of `JdbcTemplate`):

```java
LocalDateTime ts = LocalDateTime.of(2023,3,12,2,0); //DST boundary in Eastern Time Zone
List<LocalDateTime> result = template.query(
   "select * from (values(?::timestamp)) as v(ts)",
   (rs, rowNum) -> rs.getObject("ts", LocalDateTime.class), ts);
System.out.println("before, after: " + ts + ", " + result.get(0));

//results: before, after: 2023-03-12T02:00, 2023-03-12T03:00
```

3. Change my system's time zone to Hawaii time (no DST there)
4. Rerun the same code, and get:

```java
//results: before, after: 2023-03-12T02:00, 2023-03-12T02:00
```

5. Repeat the experiment except use `ts.toString()` as the parameter type
6. Observe that (before, after) in this case is (2:00, 2:00), independent of JVM timezone (i.e., a String input works as I expected LocalDateTime should work)

Is this a bug, or is this by design?

Comment: Perhaps you should run the same experiment but without *JdbcTemplate*. Just use straight JDBC.

Comment: @BasilBourque Good suggestion.  I just tried with straight JDBC, and l obtained the same results as when I used Spring's `JdbcTemplate`.

Comment: I submitted an issue.  See https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/2850.